# Is there List2D in F# like Array2D

Tags: list, f#, 2d

Do I have to use Array2D in all 2D operations then convert them to List2D? Any convenient function call or library to define and operate a 2D list?

Comment: What you want to do?

Comment: There's no such thing as a 2D list (at least I can't imagine one), but you can convert a 2D array to a list of lists (so something similar to a jagged array). I don't know why you would want to do that though.

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer:** No, there is no 2d-list.

**Longer answer:**

I think that such a type would be problematic to create, because straightforward implementations of it would either not have O(1) complexity on their equivalent of the cons operation, or break structural equality.

F# lists and arrays aren't at all the same thing. Let's recall some facts about F# lists that people would assume a 2d-version to have. They:

- are immutable
- support structural comparison
- can be iteratively built via prepending elements

The equivalent of an F# list in two dimensions can be thought of as a rectangle in a lattice-like structure such as this:

```
    N: Node           N-N-0
    0: None           | |
                    N-N-N-0
                    | | |
                N-N-N-N-N-0
                | | | | |
                0 0 0 0 0
```

Where `-` denotes that the node on the left holds a reference to the right, and `|` denotes that the node above holds a reference to the node below. Like in a one-dimensional list, each node would comprise a full 2d-list, namely of all the elements in the rectangle from itself to the last node on the bottom-right.

Since the lists should be immutable but allow iterative construction from sub-lists, creating new lists by adding a node is only valid in three cases:

- The new element is in a lowermost row of nodes
- The new element is in a rightmost column of nodes
- The elements (and therefore 2d-lists) formed by going one step down or right from the new node are non-null *and able to combine into a consistent 2d-list*.

And this is where trouble comes in. How do you tell that the two neighbors build on the same sub-lists in a structurally-compared world? You can go one step down the diagonal from the new node via the right-down and down-right paths and see whether you end up at the same element. This is fine and dandy if the results are different (fail because of invalid arguments) or referentially identical (the new 2d-list is valid), but what if their contents are equal but their identities aren't? In other words: they are different objects but may be equivalent? Now, we're forced to run through the whole thing and compare everything, or else we might end up building some mad graph that isn't two-dimensional at all.

This requires comparing the entire sub-lists, which would be the rectangle from the node one step diagonal from the newly inserted node to the bottom-rightmost node. That's not really practical; building a 2d-list of n elements like this would have O(n^2) – unless there is some form of optimization, such as keeping track of all nodes and giving equivalent nodes a unique identity.

At this point, I guess I can see why something like this didn't make it into the F# core library.